# Black Screen after upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I have a Compaq CQ58 laptop and I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After being prompted, I have updated it to the new LTS version. And after updating, everything just went to black after the reboot and am not able to log in.

Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling the OS or at least without data loss?

Comment: Do you have any graphics drivers installed before the update?

Comment: I dont think so ,or at list i dint install any proprietary drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to open in command line mode. You can do that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. You will be asked to login with your username and password.

Once you are logged in then you can check your files, for instance type `ls` to see files and folders list.

Now try this :

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: I dont actually remember the user name is there any way to do it via a live CD/USB?

Comment: Hey, I found some threads have a look they might help you

[how to recover lost username](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581088/how-to-recover-lost-username-and-password)

[how to reset a lost administrative password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)